# Eclipse and m2eclipse plugin hides parts of folder names

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

How can I stop Eclipse (Helios) and m2eclipse plug-in to hide last dotted part of folder names when importing existing maven projects into workspace?

While importing existing maven projects into workspace, that window where I select the root folder for the import, those folder names are truncated. The last dot separated part of the folder name is removed. If I have lot of folders named like "com.acme.project1", "com.acme.project2" and so on, then Eclipse shows only bunch of folders having name "com.acme". I cannot figure out which one is the correct one without opening Windows Explorer and browsing the same location and checking out real names of those folders.

I'm not sure if that is problem with m2eclipse plug-in or if it is problem with Eclipse. I don't remember seeing that problem with previous Eclipse versions.

Can anybody help? This is really annoying me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have `Hierarchical` package presentation switched on. On your `Package Explorer` view, on the top right dropdown switch to > `Package Presentation > Flat` in order to see `com.acme.project1` and `com.acme.project2` presented the one under the other in the Package Explorer.

Comment: That's not the case. Eclipse project and package explorer views are OK. I'm complaining about that window m2eclipse uses to show folders from my local hard disk when m2eclipse wants me to select root folder for project import.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but can't you use the Browse button on the right of the Root Directory path found in the Import Maven projects panel?

Comment: Of course I'm using that Browse button. How else you can open the folder list window? What's more puzzling is that sometimes folder names are truncated and sometimes not.